# Relative References in Expressions in XML bean definitions in Spring 3.0

Tags: java, spring

This is the example from the spring 3.0 reference:

```
<bean id="numberGuess" class="org.spring.samples.NumberGuess">
    <property name="randomNumber" value="#{ T(java.lang.Math).random() * 100.0 }"/>
</bean>

<bean id="shapeGuess" class="org.spring.samples.ShapeGuess">
    <property name="initialShapeSeed" value="#{ numberGuess.randomNumber }"/>
</bean>
```

But what I intend to do is something like this:

```
<bean id="foo" class="com.example.Foo">
    <property name="name" value="myName"/>
    <property name="prop">
        <bean class="com.example.Bar">
            <property name="#{ parent.name }" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

So the property *name* of the inner bean is populated with the name of the outer bean. Is this possible with the spring expression language at all? What would be the expression for something like this (parent clearly doesn't work ^^)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible in the given milestone build. They're still taking feature requests for RC1, though, so I suggest filing one.